# Javascript: How to use getter from other getters in object

Tags: javascript

Say I have this object:

```
let json = {
  Table: {
    get Total() {
      return json.Table.Items.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + item.Total, 0
      })
    },
  },
  Items: [
    {
      Quantity: 100,
      Price: 30,
      get Total() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price
      },
    },
    {
      Quantity: 200,
      Price: 20,
      get Total() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

I get 0 as Table.Total all the time, amid getting correct Totals of items. So it just doesn't sum up. I expect to get sum of all Totals but I have to get sum from getters. How would I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: "I get 0 as Table.Total" - I get "TypeError: json.Table.Items is undefined".

Comment: why calling `json` an object that has nothing to do with JSON format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues here:

1. `json.Table.Items` - There is no `Items` property inside `Table` object. So, it is anyways not working at first place.
2. Initial value `0` for the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method needs to be outside the callback like:

   ```
   json.Items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.Total, 0)
   ```
3. Also, as you are retuning a single expression inside the `.reduce()` method, you can simply return it like `.reduce((total, item) => total + item.Total, 0)`.

```js
let json = {
  Table: {
    get Total() {
      return json.Items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.Total, 0)
    }
  },
  Items: [{
      Quantity: 100,
      Price: 30,
      get Total() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price
      },
    },
    {
      Quantity: 200,
      Price: 20,
      get Total() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price
      },
    },
  ]
}

console.log( json.Table.Total )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the right object and there `Items` and move the start value of reduce outside of the function.

```js
let object = {
  Table: {
    get Total() {
      return object.Items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.Total, 0)
    }
  },
  Items: [{
      Quantity: 100,
      Price: 30,
      get Total() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price;
      }
    },
    {
      Quantity: 200,
      Price: 20,
      get Total() {
        return this.Quantity * this.Price;
      }
    }
  ]
}

console.log(object.Table.Total);
```